# Android use RxAndroid on Service

Tags: android

this below code work fine on my activity or fragments, but when i rotate my phone this method work again, how can i move that to service and get event on Ui?

```
private void getUserStories() {
    mSubscriptions.add(mDataManager.getUserPosts(mUser)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(mDataManager.getScheduler())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    hideLoadingViews();
                    Timber.e("There was a problem loading the user stories " + e);
                    DialogFactory.createSimpleOkErrorDialog(
                            getActivity(),
                            getString(R.string.error_stories)
                    ).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Post story) {
                    hideLoadingViews();
                    mPostAdapter.addItem(story);
                }
            }));
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to handle configuration changes not using service btw

Comment: Could you link me some useful topics?

Comment: You can try to google for 1)Loaders to handle orientation changes 2) retain fragment state 3) services as you suggested ;)

Comment: and take a look at this https://github.com/pmellaaho/RxApp

Comment: @AntonKazakov unfortunately I can't find any other solution about how can i use on service, for retain fragment is not good solution about this scenario